# UINavigationController Within UIPageViewController Issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I've searched and searched still cannot figure out how to fix my problem. I have a UIPageviewController as the initial view controller (like Tinder style). I want each viewController child (page) to be embedded within their own UINavigationController, so basically the page view controller will add the UINavigationController as it's child view controller.  And I'm using the setViewController method when a user taps a button in it's child view controller's navigation controller to move to the next view controller by getting a reference to the parent pageviewcontroller, as opposed to using the pageviewcontroller datasource. I don't want to use the pageviewcontroller's datasource because I don't want the swiping gesture.

However, when the user taps the button in the child's navigation controller to trigger it's parent pageviewcontroller to set the next controller, which is also a UINavigationController, the animation of doing this makes the whole screen jump up and then down.  If I remove the navigation controller and just send the view controller child instead, then it works fine. Does anyone know why embedding a navigation controller inside a pageviewcontroller would cause this issue?

Here's the code used when a user taps the bar button item in the navigation controller's navigation bar:

func pageViewControllerSetNewControllerFoward() {
        print("page view controller set matches")

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let matchesController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "matchesNav") as! UINavigationController

    parentPageViewControllerReference.setViewControllers([matchesController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely culprit of this behaviour is the `UINavigationController`trying to set it's own `UINavigationBar`. Try setting the

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` of your `UINavigationController`

Comment: Thanks for the response. @Mislav I do want each pageviewcontroller's child view controller to set it's own navigation bar items.  The pageviewcontroller is not embedded in a navigation controller, only it's children are.  And each child is the root view of their own navigation controller.   I can fix this issue if I embed the pageviewcontroller in it's own navigation controller instead of the children and have the pageviewcontroller set the navigation items.  However, this messes up the home screen card swiping functionality.....the card needs to swipe over the navigation bar.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case try pushing the initial view of the UINavigationController into the controller without the "push" animation. Maybe try making that process manual, instead of using segues and Storyboard. iOS is known for glitching when multiple system animations are happening simultaneously

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  Would I have to subclass my UINavigtionController in storyboard?  I did try removing the animation from the navigation controller view layer before the page view controller calls setViewController, but that did not work. ...like this ..... matchesController.view.layer.removeAllAnimations().  I am using a segue in storyboard from the navigation controller to the child controller. Thanks again!  @Mislav

Comment: Hi, In your storyboard -  just remove the segue that connects the UINavigationController and the initial ViewController. Then, manually instantiate your ViewController just like you instantiated the UINavigationController and then just call navCont.pushViewController(viewController: yourVc, animated: false). Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Oh yeah...duh...my brain is fried from days of trying to fix various UI issues related to this.  I tried and it still did the animation jerk up and down.  I added these two lines of code to my code above.....

let matches = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "matchesTable") as! MatchesTableViewController

matchesController.pushViewController(matches, animated: false)

@Mislav  Thanks!

Comment: The reason I want the view controllers to have their own navigation controller is because I'm able to get the card to swipe over the navigation bar is if I add the card view to the navigation controller's view instead of it's view controller's view.  As a workaround I also tried getting rid of all navigation controllers and added navigation bars to every screen and am using the page view controller to add all view controllers, which has caused me some new issues.   So, I really prefer to use my initial setup. @Mislav

Comment: Yeah, the lines are exactly what I thought. If it didn't fix it, then I guess it's out of my league. Best of luck solving the issue :)

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help.  Thanks!  @Mislav

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by setting **`Automatically Adjust Scroll Views`** to `false` for the `PageViewController` and `NavigationViewControllers`.

Do so by `self.pageViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` or easier still in Interface Builder under attributes>layout>`Adjust Scroll View Insets set` to `false`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I believe I did try that at the time and it did not work, but I decided for a few reasons to change the UI anyways, so it's no longer an issue for me.  Thanks!